# Can you use more than 1 case in a MySQLi query?

Tags: mysql

This query is complex for me. The first case works. I tried to add the second case; however, can't get it to work.  Does a case require more than 1 when statements? Am I doing the second case wrong altogether?

The only reason I need the second case is because when `table1.data_lock = 0`, there is no `table2.id` that is equal to 0.  I only want it to include the `table2 IF table1.data_lock != 0`

There may be a better way of doing this.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.draft_sectionid, table1.page_columnid, table1.sortid, 
(case 
when table1.data_lock = 0 then table1.data 
when table1.data_lock != 0 then table2.data
end) as data,
table1.style
 FROM table1

 (case 
when table1.data_lock != 0 then JOIN table2 ON table1.data_lock=table2.id
end)

  WHERE table1.draft_sectionid = " . $section['id'] . " ORDER BY table1.sortid ASC LIMIT " . $section['columns']) or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: I guess you can only use Case in SELECT statement, not after FROM

Comment: yeah.  I think you are right superB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use case-when to define the structure of the select.

However, in this case you can use subselect to produce the value:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.draft_sectionid, table1.page_columnid, table1.sortid, 
(case 
when table1.data_lock = 0 then table1.data 
when table1.data_lock != 0 then (select table2.data from table2 where table2.id = table1.data_lock)
end) as data,
table1.style
 FROM table1
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can's use a `CASE` expression for changing join table likewise you are trying. You can change your query to be like below using a outer join

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.draft_sectionid, table1.page_columnid, table1.sortid, 
(case when table1.data_lock = 0 then table1.data 
      else table2.data end) as data,
table1.style

FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.data_lock != 0 AND table1.data_lock = table2.id
WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL 
AND table1.draft_sectionid = " . $section['id'] . " 
ORDER BY table1.sortid ASC 
LIMIT " 1;
```

Comment: is this a better method than doing a subselect as recommended in another answer?

Comment: @KDJ, instead I say which is better ... why not you run it, generate the query plan and test yourself.

Comment: I just mean is it a better way of coding.  Taking security and taking practicality into question.  I'm partially doing this to learn.  Both will work, I just didn't know which was a more proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.draft_sectionid, table1.page_columnid, table1.sortid, 
(case 
when table1.data_lock = 0 then table1.data 
when table1.data_lock != 0 then table2.data
end) as data,
table1.style
 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.data_lock=table2.id and table1.data_lock != 0 

WHERE table1.draft_sectionid = " . $section['id'] . " ORDER BY table1.sortid ASC LIMIT " . $section['columns']) or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($connection));
mysqli
```

Use this query.